# Java EE Entity Manager is not fetching properly the database data

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee

I made a little Java EE program,

```
...
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Article getIt() {

    EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("local_persistence")
            .createEntityManager();

    Article a = em.find(Article.class, 1);
    return a;
}
...
```

and here is my `persistence.xml` file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="local_persistence" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:app/local-db</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The `jta-data-source` seems correct because when I deploy and run the application, the json is displayed properly with the `Article` data :

```
{"articleId":1,"content":"hello everyone","name":"my first article"}
```

However, if I made a change of the row in the local database and reload the page (not the application), the json is unchanged.

Why doesn't the resource fetch again the data in the database ?

Comment: How did you change the data in the database? Using mysql workbench? if so did you commit the change?

Comment: Did you commit?

Comment: it is a postgresql database, i did commit because I wrote `update prog.articles set content='...' where article_id=1;`

Comment: Add your hbm file as well for the Article table

Comment: If you are sure that you have commited, another explanation could be PersistenceContext is not refreshed, it supplies data from cache. try `em.refresh(Article.class, 1)`;

Comment: The value will be cached

Comment: clear your cache

Comment: Just a hint: do not create EntityManagerFactory on every request. It is slow operation. You should create EntityManager per request. Start factory on application start.